# Angular UI Bootstrap v0.11 datepicker popup not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Just switched to v0.11 of UI Bootstrap and the datepicker-popup is no longer working.

It works fine with v0.10.  Anyone know what has been changed in the new version which might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.  I should have checked the github first.

There is a bug report on the datepicker.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2180